# Getting data from another Google sheet that isn't in the same order

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, vlookup

I have a very basic knowledge of deeper functions of Google sheets and solving this has been a little bit of pain in the butt so far.

I have a spreadsheet A

- column A contains ID
- column I that has the info that I need to receive

I have spreadsheet B

- in my column X I need to get the exact data that is in spreadsheet A, column I

the thing is these two spreadsheets don't have the same order of IDs so basically I need it first look for the correct ID, THEN to duplicate data into my spreadsheet B, column X.
Column A in both sheets contain IDs, just assorted compared to each other.

Hopefully, this explanation is understandable enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(W2:W; 
 IMPORTRANGE("17FPRpPL0ieLGAw1971urLUu_egG7bMBqDtpzRk6-_ic"; 
 "Sheet1!A2:I"); 9; 0); ))
```

[image]

- **`W2:W`** in your case **`A1:A`**
- **`17FPRpPL0ieLGAw1971urLUu_egG7bMBqDtpzRk6-_ic`** needs to be changed for yours (spreadsheet A)
- **`Sheet1!A2:I`** will need to have actual sheet name (the part before **`!`**)
- **`9`** is column number of column **`I`**
- if you get **`#REF!`** error first use **`=IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL", "Sheet1!A2:A")`** and allow access and then use that array formula with vlookup from above

Comment: Hello, firstly thank you a lot for your time and effort! I have tried what you said and I got #ERROR!, so I have tried only the importrange function and it had access to the spreadsheet A so I guess the problem is somewhere in my formula: **=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE("link_to_my_spreadsheet_B"; "sheet_I_need!A4:I"), 9, 0), ))**. A4 is the first cell with ID so I guess I should use that row number, right?

Comment: I have imported all data into my spreadsheet B under a separate sheet with **IMPORTRANGE** formula so I think now I can work with the data easier, right? I have tried to only use **VLOOKUP** for the rest of the job but it says that it expects a _number_ and my data is in _text_ (even tried changing the format to text and vice versa but that didn't help)

Comment: @MarekMarhoul can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: what the #ERROR! message said? yes for A4. try changing every `,` to `;` - that's the reason for the error I guess.

Comment: answer updated. first column of the 2nd argument of the VLOOKUP needs to be the one where the 1st argument of VLOOKUP looks up for match

Comment: The Error message said something like Error in analysing the formula (I have it in different language than English so I don't know the exact wording)  
---
Dummy sheet A [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U4yYfEqout_j6-eqI7idn-perCOccUMVbSLFWDMmHZ0/edit#gid=0)  
Dummy sheet B [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17IlYntADTmnT3tExh0LsUpENLfX2aJzGmseDSX31SvI/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Hello again, I have an update for my previous question - is there an easy way to extend the search formula to browse 2 sheets? So the ID that the formula is looking for in Spreadsheet B is eithe in sheet 1 or sheet 2 in the same position.

Comment: yes, it would be possible. you just need to construct a virtual table with `{}` consisting of Sheet1 and Sheet2

Comment: Great, it's working! Thank you  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B;{Sheet1!A2:AG; Sheet2!A2:AG}; 24; 0)))`